# Question regarding pointwise convergence of Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

Suppose I have a continuous function $\psi(x)$ on the interval $[0,1]$
and we have
$$
\sum_m | \hat \psi (m)| < \infty.
$$
Could someone please explain me how it follows that the $\psi(x)$
is the sum of its Fourier series?

Thank you!

Comment: Fourier series with respect to $e^{2\pi i n t}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that
$$
\sum_{m\in\mathbb Z}\big|\hat\psi(m)\big|<\infty,
$$
implies that the sequence of the partial Fourier sums
$$
\psi_n(x)=\sum_{|m|\le n}\hat\psi(m)\,\mathrm{e}^{imx},
$$
converges uniformly to a continuous function which has Fourier coefficients $\hat\psi(m)$'s
and thus coincides with $\psi$ - i.e., $\psi$ is a sum of its Fourier series.